# Export blender data to opengl

Tags: python, c++, opengl, blender

I'm writing a graphic library using opengl and c++. In the class I have implemented all the geometric stuff( like linear transformations) and all the things that make opengl to work ( like shader, texture and so on). 
So i've decided to create particular object that have as parent class the previous one using blender.

I've created a simple table in blender like this: 
[image]

Then i created and execute this script to get the coordinates and the indicies using the python console:

```
import bpy

obj=bpy.context.active_object
name=obj.name+".h";
f=open(name,"w")

scale=1
st_app="float verticies_ble[{}]=".format(str(len(obj.data.vertices)*3))+"{\n"
f.write(st_app)

for v in obj.data.vertices:
    f.write("\t\t"+str(v.co[0]/scale)+"f,"+str(v.co[1]/scale)+"f,"+str(v.co[2]/scale)+"f")
    f.write(",\n")

f.seek(f.tell()-2)
st_app="}"+";\n\nconst GLuint indicies_ble[{}]=".format(str(len(obj.data.polygons)*3))+"{\n"
f.write(st_app)


for poly in obj.data.polygons:
    f.write("\t\t"+str(poly.vertices[0])+","+str(poly.vertices[1])+","+str(poly.vertices[2])+",\n")
f.seek(f.tell()-2)
f.write("};\n")

f.close()
```

I use the output and i create the obj table and executing it i can see that:
[image]
[image]

The problem is that the diagonals are drawed and i want only the border.
Now my question is i only want to draw border, so is there a way using python to get only the indicies for the border? Thank and sorry for the english.

Comment: opengl is very low level. graphics libraries like irrlicht, opencv and ogre3d are built on it and they understand meshes etc.

Comment: I know but i don't care. I want to make it using the lowest  way

Comment: Looks like your vertex buffer is incorrect. You might want to go through the list of generated vertices

Comment: The vertex buffer is correct. I used the GL_POINTS to draw only the vertexes and they're correct. The problem  is with the indices buffer

Comment: Then mapping of indices is not correct.

Comment: I know. As i said i'm searching a way to to use python to get only the border indices. And not the diagonals

Comment: @P.Carlino You have the right vertices, you are just drawing them the wrong way, the faces section of [this tutorial](http://sinestesia.co/blog/tutorials/python-2d-grid/) might help explain it. I think you may also be missing some data, you are exporting three verts per face where I think you expect four.

Comment: What format are you using to export your 3d object?

Comment: As you can see  the script generate a .h header file

Comment: Try to export it as obj, you can easily create a objloader on Python or just use existing one. Your vertices are correct, but your edges are bad formed, this fact is causing that some vertices join to others.

Comment: I know and that is caused by indices.  I  want to  export them because my library is written  in c++ and i want to continue in c++